# Kafka Rebalancing issues when I kill one consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

There is a very weird flow happening in the following case

1. I have 6 consumer processes running connected to a cluster of 3 brokers. 3 of the consumers (set A) are subscribed to a particular set of topics (topics C) and the other 3 consumers (set B) are subscribed to another set of topics (topics D). All the consumers belong to the same consumer group. All the topics have a replication factor of 3 and are divided into 24 partitions. Each consumer is automatically assigned to 8 partitions of the topic set it is supposed to consume. I have set the assignment pattern to round robin.
2. If I kill a consumer from set A, topics C are repartitioned successfully in the remaining consumers from set A. Each consumer in set A is now subscribed to 12 partitions from topics C.
3. But consumers in set B go crazy. All topics and all partitions in D are assigned to any one consumer from B and the rest of the consumers remain idle - All 24 partitions of all topics in set D are assigned to a single process.

I need some idea on how to debug this and what could be the issue?

I believe only the consumers in topic C should be affected. Consumer set B should remain unaffected and definitely not assign all partitions to a single process

Kafka version is 0.11

Comment: It is very difficult to understand your question as you are not using Kafka vocabulary. So far I got that you have a Kafka Cluster with 3 Brokers. Then you have n topics, for each topic you have to specify the replication factor and the number of partitions. Finally for each consumer you should tell us to which topics they subscribe and to which consumer group they belong.

Comment: have updated the question with this info @pgras. Let me know if you want more details

Comment: So you have n topics in set C (Topic C1, ..., Topic Cn) and 3 consumers in set A (Consumer A1, ... Consumer A3). Each consumer from set A subscribed to the n topics in set C. You have a second set D of m topics (Topic D1, ... , Topic Dm) and 3 consumers in set B (Consumer B1, B3) each consumer subscibed to the M topics? The only thing that is shared is the consumer group which is identical for the 6 consumers? What else is shared but Kafka itself? Are all the consumers running in their own JVM?

Comment: yes they are running in their own individual environments. nothing else is shared. @pgras

Comment: @pgras any help here?

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding everything well. If you have some consumers reading from some topics, and other consumers reading from other different topics, why are you using the same consumer group for all consumers? Probably you can use different consumer group and avoid problems with repartitions